# Edit private tag with Pydicom

Tags: tags, private, dicom, pydicom

I am trying to edit a private tag from a RTPLAN with Pydicom

First, I read the dicom file :
ds = dicom.read_file(*'dicomfile'*)

The tag I want to modify is [image]

I tried the command : *ds[0x4001, 0x1012] = 'test'*

but it returns the following error :

*TypeError: Dataset items must be 'DataElement' instances*

How could I modify the value of that tag ?

Comment: Not the whole answer, but the problem is probably that the value representation (the "data type") of private attributes is unknown. So pydicom cannot know how to binary endoce the string that you are passing (or if that is an allowed value at all - the attribute might be floating point). So you probably need to add the attributes to the private dictionary: https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/datadict.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer, since the private data element already exists in this case, is to simply change its *value*:

```py
 ds[0x4001,0x1012].value = b'test'
```

Another answer is to look at the [documentation on working with Private Data Elements](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/old/private_data_elements.html) where more flexible ways of working with them are described.

Comment: You might need `b'test'` here - I can't recall but I think with VR of UN, pydicom would not modify the Python unicode to a byte string on writing later.  Edited the answer to put that in.